# Funcion con condiciones y trigger para evaluar las modificaciones de una tabla

Tags: sql, postgresql, trigger, function

Estoy tratando de hacer modificaciones sobre una tabla mediante PostgreSQL y no estoy seguro de estar haciéndolo bien.

La tabla `tb_invoice` tiene los siguientes atributos: net_amount, iva_amount, tot_amount y algunos otros atributos que no son necesarios en este caso.

Quiero que se actualicen los atributos cada vez que se inserte, modifique o elimine cualquier registro de otra tabla (`tb_lines`) con estos mismos atributos entre otros.

Lo que he hecho es lo siguiente:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_update_amount() 
RETURNS trigger AS $$
BEGIN
  IF (erp.tb_invoice.iva_amount <>0) OR
     (erp.tb_invoice.net_amount <> 0) THEN
    NEW.erp.tb_invoice.tot_amount = erp.tb_invoice.iva_amount + erp.tb_invoice.net_amount; 
  END IF;
  RETURN NEW;
END
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'; 

CREATE TRIGGER tg_update_amount
  BEFORE UPDATE ON erp.tb_invoice
  FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION fn_update_amount();
```

Una de mis dudas es si la condición es correcta. Quiero evaluar si ha cambiado 'iva_amount' o 'net_amount' y en ese caso, actualizar 'tot_amount' haciendo la suma y devolviendo ese valor.

La otra forma que veo que se podría hacer la condición es así:

```
...
  IF (NEW.erp.tb_invoice.iva_amount IS DISTINCT FROM OLD.erp.tb_invoice.iva_amount) OR
     (NEW.erp.tb_invoice.net_amount IS DISTINCT FROM OLD.erp.tb_invoice.net_amount) THEN
...
```

Estaría bien en ambos casos?

Además, estaba tratando de hacerlo con un trigger.

Gracias por las aclaraciones.

Comment: En teoria estaria bien lo que planteas.

Comment: @AnthonySotolongo, tanto con ```(erp.tb_invoice.iva_amount <>0) OR``` como con ```(NEW.erp.tb_invoice.iva_amount IS DISTINCT FROM OLD.erp.tb_invoice.iva_amount) OR``` entonces? Muchas gracias!

Comment: En los personal prefiero `<>` :)

Comment: @AnthonySotolongo, acabo de ejecutar el código y tengo un error de sintaxis.  ```ERROR:  error de sintaxis en o cerca de «NEW»
LINE 7:    NEW.erp.tb_invoice.tot_amount = erp.tb_invoice.iva_amount...```  Voy a plantearlo como otra pregunta en el foro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error que menciono abajo queda solucionado con el código siguiente:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_update_amount() 
RETURNS trigger AS $$
BEGIN
  IF (erp.tb_invoice.iva_amount <>0) OR
     (erp.tb_invoice.net_amount <> 0) THEN
    NEW.tot_amount = iva_amount + net_amount; 
  END IF;
  RETURN NEW;
END
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'; 

--DROP TRIGGER tg_update_amount ON erp.tb_invoice;

CREATE TRIGGER tg_update_amount
  BEFORE UPDATE ON erp.tb_invoice
  FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION fn_update_amount();
```

El error de mi planteamiento se encontraba en

```
NEW.erp.tb_invoice.tot_amount = erp.tb_invoice.iva_amount + erp.tb_invoice.net_amount;
```

No se debe indicar la base de datos ni la tabla, simplemente basta con indicar el atributo.